# Independent Variables (Discrete Maths)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A binary string of length $4$ is selected uniformly at random. Let $Y$ and $Z$ be random variables
so that $Y$ is the numbers of $1s$ in the entire string and $Z$ is the number of $1s$ in the first two
bits of the string.

(i) Find $Pr(Y = 1)$ and $Pr(Z = 2)$.

(ii) Find $Pr(Y = 1 ∧ Z = 2)$.

(iii) Are the events “$Y = 2$” and “$Z = 2$” independent?

my answer for part $(i)$ is 1/4 for $pr(Y=1)$ and $\frac{1}{4}$ for $pr(Y=2)$ as well. To explain my answer for $pr(Y=1)$ is that there can be 4 different values in each bit and they said there is only one $1$ in the whole string so thats how I got $\frac{1}{4}$.

BUT I am not sure if this is the right answer and I need some help on the second and third part as well. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I am misreading, but if $Z$ is the number of $1's$ in the first two slots and $Y$ is the number of $1's$ in the entire string then you can't have $Y=1,Z=2$.

Comment: I agree with your value for $P(Y=1)$ but not your reasoning (well, I can't follow your reasoning).  There are $16$ possible binary words of length $4$ and there are exactly $4$ that have exactly $1$ one, namely $0001,0010,0100,1000$.  Thus the answer is $\frac 4{14}=\frac 14$.

Answer (score 0):

For $P(Y = 1)$, you fix one of the values to $1$ and see the possible number of arrangements of the remaining $3$ over the total number of arrangements of the bit string, which is $3!/ 4! = 6/24 = 1/4$. For $P(Z= 2)$ fix the first two elements to be $1$ and recognize there are 3 possible arrangements of this form ($1100, 1110, 1111)$ and divide this by the total number of arrangements, $2^4$ , so $P(Z = 2) = 3/16$.

$P(Y = 1) \land P(Z = 2)$ is $0$ because if $Y=1$ then $Z$ can at most equal 1.

The intersection of $P(Y = 2)$ and $P(Z = 2)$ is not empty (for example the bit string $1100$ is true for both parameters, so they are not independent events.